# How to show array columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I am selecting data from a Postgres database, and one of these columns is of type `TEXT[]`. I bind the data source to a `DataGridView`, but those array columns just don't show up (`dgData` is a `DataGridView`).

```
dgData.DataSource = getDataTable();
```

When I now inspect `((DataTable)dgData.DataSource).Columns[15].DataType`, I get the value `{Name = "String[]" FullName = "System.String[]"}`, showing me that this is a string array. This column is just gone in the rendering of the `DataGrid`.

How can I show that data?

Comment: What do you expect? The 1st of the strings? Does the debugger show credible data for the Cells' Values?

Comment: @TaW well, I did expect a comma separated list, or some rendering that `psql` gives me. But come to think of it now, I don't really know what to expect.

Comment: `getDataTable` returns a data table? You need to inspect what exact value you are getting in DataTable for that column. You need to convert that to comma separated values before binding it to data grid view. Auto column binding will not treat data differently.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: "You need to convert that to comma separated values before binding it to data grid view. " How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a `DataGridView` will accept a column of type `string[]`.

**If** it did you could use the `CellFormatting` event to create a nicely formatted display version of your data, maybe like so:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                          DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourIndexOrName1 && e.Value != null)
    {
        var s = e.Value as string[];
        e.Value = String.Join(", ", s);
    }
}
```

**But** the Column neither gets created (when using `AutoGenerateColumns`) nor gets filled otherwise.

**So** you should create a **readily formatted column**. Either in **SQL** at the database level or later in a **Linq** line.

Example:

```
var dt_ = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => new {
    f1 = x.Field<string>(0),
    f2 = x.Field<string[]>(1).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j),
    f3 = x.Field<int>(2)
});

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt_.ToList();
```

Using my test data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string[]));
dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(int));

var row = dt.NewRow();
row.SetField<string>("col1",  "A");
row.SetField<string[]>("col2", new string[] { "abc", "xyz", "123" });
row.SetField<int>("col3", 23 );
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row = dt.NewRow();
row.SetField<string>("col1", "B");
row.SetField<string[]>("col2", new string[] { "a-b-c", "x+y+z", "1:2:3" });
row.SetField<int>("col3", 42);
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

While this means indeed that you need to take care for each field, imo the autogeneration of columns is not as powerful and flexible as one would wish, when it gets down to production code..

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to fix it some other way. Funny thing though, I also have a `hstore` column, which is mapped to an `IDictionary`, which does get rendered in the `DataGridView`, as `(Collection)`.

Comment: Hm, intersting; what does get displayed? The Key, both keys and values? Or does it have a ToString method?

Comment: is says `(Collection)` literally.

Comment: Ok, that (the classname) is the default output when a proper ToString method is missing. Which means that the column is being filled, which means that you can use the CellFormatting event to convert the data to a readable version..